# ReactDOM does not render component into html

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux

Just started redux, get stuck on a weird situation, webpack shows no error, but in the html, the component did not get rendered. The file structure:

```
dist
  bundle.js
node_modules
src
  index.js
.babelrc
index.html
package.json
server.js
webpack.config.js
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jie blog</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

</body>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js">
    </script>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, Redirect, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'

class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                hello world
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,     
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

server.js

```
var http = require('http')
var express = require('express')
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy')
var fs = require('fs')

var babelrc = fs.readFileSync('./.babelrc')
var config = JSON.parse(babelrc)
require('babel-core/register')(config)

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({})

var app = express()

app.use(require('morgan')('short'))

// webpack
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('./webpack.config')
var compiler = webpack(config)

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
    noInfo: true, 
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath
}))
app.use(require('webpack-hot-middleware')(compiler))




app.all(/^\/api\/(.*)/, function api(req, res){
    proxy.web(req, res, {
        target: 'http://localhost:5000'
    })
})

app.get(/.*/, function root(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

const server = http.createServer(app)
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
    const address = server.address()
    console.log('listening on %j', address)
})
```

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map', 
    entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client', 
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.js')
    ], 
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), 
        filename: 'bundle.js', 
        publicPath: '/static/'
    }, 
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.jsx', '.js', '.json', '.scss']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
              test: /\.jsx?$/,
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              exclude: /node_modules/, 
              query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'react']
              }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

output html

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>


    <script src="dist/bundle.js">
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your script tags are spelled `scirpt`.  Not sure if that's your problem.

Comment: actually, I got an error in console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bundler.js:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks it's not an issue with ReactDOM but instead a configuration problem.

In server.js

```
...

app.use(require('webpack-dev-middleware')(compiler, {
  noInfo: true, 
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath // <--- /static/ 
}))

...
```

`publicPath` specifies the public URL address of your bundle.js when referenced in a browser. So /static/bundle.js as you set in your webpack.config.js. Ok fine !

So Index.html need to request for /static/bundle.js. and **NOT** dist/bundle.js

```
...

<script src="static/bundle.js"></script>

...
```

### Check [output.publicPath configurations for webpack](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/configuration#outputpublicpath) for more informations

As index.html requested for your bundle at `/dist` and `webpack-dev-middleware` handle requests at `/static`, an index.html file was returned instead of a your bundle.js

```
app.get(/.*/, function root(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')  
})
```

It's why you got `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < bundler.js:1`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Babel is transpiling only .jsx files:

```
test: /\.jsx?$/,
```

while your file with JSX has a .js extension (index.js)

Comment: it will take .js or .jsx